# Where to save this class?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, architecture, save

Updated models.Model:

```
class GetOrNoneManager(models.Manager):
    """returns none if object doesn't exist else model instance"""

    def get_or_none(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.get(**kwargs)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
            logger.warning(e)
            return None


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('-created_at',)

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания', auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Дата изменения', auto_now=True)
    objects = GetOrNoneManager()

    def str(self):
        return self.id.hex
```

Is there any certain file that i should create to save code like that?

Comment: Please don't add garbage text to get past our quality filters. They are there to help _you_ as much as us, by encouraging you to invest more in writing a good question.

Comment: what is trying to do? can you edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to put this in the models.py file in the app that is going to use that manager/model pair; so something like:

```
main_folder
|   manage.py
|
└───YourProject
|       settings.py
|       urls.py
|       wsgy.py
|
└───YourApp
        models.py <-- This file
```

Should be absolutely fine; although I would suggest your tweak your docstring because it looks like your .get_or_none()'s definition is in the class and not on the method.
Another way to do this is to create an app that is going to be holding that information to minimize cross dependency:

```
main_folder
|   manage.py
|
└───YourProject
|       settings.py
|       urls.py
|       wsgy.py
|
└───MyCustomManagers
        managers.py <- GetOrNoneManager goes here
        models.py <- BaseModel goes here
```

That way you can create multiple apps and they can all have models that extend that class that you created and they will all depend on the MyCustomManagers app (please see that this is not a very good naming convention since MyCustomManagers is not super descriptive).